# MySQL - Using already defined classes in NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to select all proposals that are not voted `ProProposalBundle:Proposal\Vote`. There may exist a `"not_voted"` value in `v.decision`, or may not. That's why I used `NOT EXIST`.

```
SELECT p 
FROM ProProposalBundle:Proposal p 
INNER JOIN ProProposalBundle:Proposal\Vote v 
    WITH v.proposal = p 
        AND (v.decision = 'not_voted' OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT v FROM v WHERE v.user = {$user})) 
WHERE p.community = {$community}
```

but it returns me an error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 181 near 'v WHERE v.user': Error: Class 'v' is not defined.
```

and it's related to the `NOT EXISTS` part, where `v` is theoretically defined before. I've also tried to do:

```
... NOT EXISTS (SELECT v FROM ProProposalBundle:Proposal\Vote v WHERE v.user = {$user}))
```

but now I'm getting:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 220 near 'v WHERE v.user': Error: 'v' is already defined.
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There can only be exactly zero or one record per (user,proposal) in the `Vote` table?

Comment: @VolkerK - Yes. One record per user and proposal. Or none!

Comment: No solution here but a) you are using doctrine, right? and b) it seems to be its (doctrine's) parser complaining not the MySQL server? In that case you might want to add `doctrine` as a tag. Are you positive that you can't express the query through doctrine's query-builder thingy? (sorry, I'm completely unfamiliar with doctrine).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProProposalBundle:Proposal\Vote v WHERE v.user = {$user}))
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.